# Running GNU Parallel Java Job

Tags: java, terminal, parallel-processing, bigdata, gnu-parallel

Is this the correct way to execute a java job with the input `myFile.txt`? What I want to do is to run the MyJavaClass program with the input given into args[0], however, I want to run this locally on my machine on multiple cores rather than on a cluster.

```
parallel java MyJavaClass ::: myFile.txt
```

EDIT:

What I want to accomplish is the following:

```
java MyJavaClass arg1 arg2 arg3 
java MyJavaClass arg4 arg5 arg6
java MyJavaClass arg7 arg8 arg9
```

and I would like these jobs to run in parallel

Comment: Do you want to run N copies of exactly the same job in parallel, where N is the number of cores in your CPU? If so, yes.

Comment: Can you give three examples of commands you want run by GNU Parallel?
It makes it easier to understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: What I am trying to do is run 10 copies of the same job with different inputs in parallel, so I would like to execute MyJavaClass with myFile1, myFile2, .... ,myFile10 as input in parallel

Comment: Can you give three examples of commands you want run by GNU Parallel? Write them all the way out on 3 separate lines and do not put them in comments. It makes it easier to understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @OleTange added edit

Comment: Where do arg1 arg2 arg3 come from?

Comment: They're input arguments, so they would be args[0], args[1] and args[2] in java

Comment: I understand that the args go _to_ java. But where do they come _from_? How do you give them to GNU Parallel? Are they in a file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159432/discussion-between-mankee-and-ole-tange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `myFile.txt` with millions of lines, and you want this split into one chunk per CPU core, and then run `MyJavaClass` on that input, and we assume that `MyJavaClass` reads from stdin (standard input) and prints to stdout (standard output) so the 3 lines would look something like this:

```
cat chunk1 | java MyJavaClass > output1
cat chunk2 | java MyJavaClass > output2
cat chunk3 | java MyJavaClass > output3
```

then it looks like this using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -a myFile.txt --pipepart --block -1 java MyJavaClass > combined_output
```

If `MyJavaClass` instead takes a filename so the 3 lines look like this:

```
java MyJavaClass chunk1 > output1
java MyJavaClass chunk2 > output2
java MyJavaClass chunk3 > output3
```

then this may work:

```
# --fifo is fast, but may not work if MyJavaClass seeks into the file
parallel -a myFile.txt --pipepart --fifo --block -1 java MyJavaClass {} > combined_output
# --cat creates temporary files
parallel -a myFile.txt --pipepart --cat --block -1 java MyJavaClass {} > combined_output
```

If `MyJavaClass` outputs to a filename, so the 3 lines look like this

```
java MyJavaClass chunk1 --output-file chunk1.output
java MyJavaClass chunk2 --output-file chunk2.output
java MyJavaClass chunk3 --output-file chunk3.output
```

you can then use that `{#}` is the job number and thus is unique:

```
parallel [...] java MyJavaClass {} --output-file {#}.output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parallel java MyJavaClass ::: myFile.txt
```

will run:

```
java MyJavaClass myFile.txt
```

Whereas:

```
parallel java MyJavaClass ::: myFile1.txt myFile2.txt
```

will run these in parallel:

```
java MyJavaClass myFile1.txt
java MyJavaClass myFile2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file `myargs` contains:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4
arg5
arg6
arg7
arg8
arg9
```

and you want to run:

```
java MyJavaClass arg1 arg2 arg3
java MyJavaClass arg4 arg5 arg6
java MyJavaClass arg7 arg8 arg9
```

then you can do:

```
parallel -N3 java MyJavaClass :::: myargs
```

Comment: and what if I want each of these jobs to be executed on one core only so we have 3 cores in total in the above example, rather than splitting each of these jobs among the different cores?